# NIntegrate warns about Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages, nonlinear

Executing the following code, `NDSolve` begins to solve a system of two coupled ordinary differential equations for the dependent variables $\rho_0(t)$ and $\lambda_k(t)$. Around $t=-2$ `NIntegrate` warns that

> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand [...] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,4.64782*10^14}}.

causing `NDSolve` to abort. Could some `NIntegrate`-whiz tell me what's wrong with my integrand? I looked at it in various 3d plots and it appears completely regular. I tried rerunning the calculation with different values for `WorkingPrecision` and `MaxRecursion` in case `NIntegrate` was having difficulties with small numbers, but without success. Any other suggestions how to diagnose this further and get `NDSolve` to solve my ODEs would be much appreciated!

```
sqrt[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]=Piecewise[{{I Sqrt[-x],Re[x]<0&&Re[y]>=0},{-I Sqrt[-x],Re[x]<0&&Re[y]<0}},Sqrt[x]];
Derivative[1,0][sqrt][x_,y_]=1/(2sqrt[x,y]);
Derivative[0,1][sqrt][x_,y_]=0;

αk[1,1][m2_,g2_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2/z-I g2/z)+I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2/z+I g2/z)^2,-(1/c-m2/z)];
αk[1,2][m2_,g2_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2/z+I g2/z)-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2/z-I g2/z)^2,(1/c-m2/z)];
αk[2,1][m2_,g2_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2/z-I g2/z)-I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2/z+I g2/z)^2,-(1/c-m2/z)];
αk[2,2][m2_,g2_,z_,c_]:=1/2 (1/c+m2/z+I g2/z)+I sqrt[1/(c z)-1/4 (1/c-m2/z-I g2/z)^2,(1/c-m2/z)];

w={1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-2,2};
μ=Join[Flatten@Table[αk[i,j][m2/s^2,g2/s^2,z,c]s^2,{s,{k,Λ}},{i,2},{j,2}],{k^2/c,Λ^2/c}];

ΔkerT=T Sum[w[[j]]Log[Exp[1/T Sqrt[p^2+μ[[j]]]]-1],{j,10}];
kerT[0][m2_,g2_,z_,c_,T_,p_]=k D[ΔkerT,k]/.k->1;
kerT[j_][m2_,g2_,z_,c_,T_,p_]:=(-1)^j Derivative[j,0,0,0,0,0][kerT[0]][m2,g2,z,c,T,p];

tfI[j_][m2_,g2_,z_,T_,c_,d_,pmax_,ops___]:=(2π^(d/2))/((2π)^d Gamma[d/2]) NIntegrate[kerT[j][m2,g2,z,c,T,p] p^(d-1),{p,0,pmax},ops];

ρ0Flow[ρ0_?NumericQ,λk_?NumericQ,ηk_?NumericQ,g2_?NumericQ,Z1_?NumericQ,T_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ,d_?NumericQ,N_?NumericQ,pmax_,ops___]:=-(2+ηk)ρ0+(3/2 tfI[1][2ρ0 λk,g2,Z1,T,c,d,pmax,ops]+(N-1)/2tfI[1][0,0,1,T,c,d,pmax,ops])
λkFlow[ρ0_?NumericQ,λk_?NumericQ,ηk_?NumericQ,g2_?NumericQ,Z1_?NumericQ,T_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ,d_?NumericQ,N_?NumericQ,pmax_,ops___]:=2ηk λk+λk^2 (9/2 tfI[2][2ρ0 λk,g2,Z1,T,c,d,pmax,ops]+(N-1)/2tfI[2][0,0,1,T,c,d,pmax,ops])

AbsoluteTiming@Module[{runner = 0, counter = 0},
  With[{ηk = 0, g2 = 0, Z1 = 1, T = 0.1 E^t, c = 1, d = 3, N = 2,
     pmax = ∞}, 
   run[1] = 
    NDSolve[{ρ0'[
        t] == ρ0Flow[ρ0[t], λk[t], ηk, g2, Z1, 
        T, c, d, N, pmax], λk'[
        t] == λkFlow[ρ0[t], λk[t], ηk, g2, 
        Z1, T, c, d, N, pmax], ρ0[0] == 0.02, λk[0] == 
       0.5}, {ρ0, λk}, {t, -10, 0}, 
     StepMonitor :> 
      counter++ If[Abs[t] > runner, 
        Print@Chop[{counter, Round[t, 1], 
           E^(2 t) ρ0[t], λk[t]}]; runner++]]]]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's odd. I reach $t = -2$ in about 40 seconds using MMA 11.2 on macOS 10.13. What's your system?

Comment: I thought I was using 11.2, but it turns out I pasted it into the beta...Well, that's something to look forward to, hmm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NIntegrate` fails when the arguments of exponentials in the integrand become too large, causing overflows.  This can be seen by removing unnecessary code from `AbsoluteTiming@NDSolve ...` and enclosing it in `EvaluationData` as follows.

```
With[{ηk = 0, g2 = 0, Z1 = 1, T = 0.1 E^t, c = 1, d = 3, n = 2, pmax = ∞},  
    EvaluationData[NDSolve[{ρ0'[t] == ρ0Flow[ρ0[t], λk[t], ηk, g2, Z1, T, c, d, n, pmax], 
    λk'[t] == λkFlow[ρ0[t], λk[t], ηk, g2, Z1, T, c, d, n, pmax], 
    ρ0[0] == 0.02, λk[0] == 0.5}, {ρ0, λk}, {t, -10, 0}]]];
```

Which produces an enormous expression and many error messages.  (Note that `N` has been replaced by `n` everywhere in the code in the question, because `N` is a Mathematica function.  Using this reserved symbol is not, however, the source of the problem in the question.)  The `NIntegrate` integrand that caused the error then is obtained from

```
Cases[%, Hold[Message[NIntegrate::inumri, z__]] -> z, Infinity, 1]
```

which also is very large but contains 18 terms of the general form

```
-(((29.0983 + 50.3998 I) E^(116.393 Sqrt[1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + p^2]))/
    ((-1 + E^(116.393 Sqrt[1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + p^2])) (1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + p^2)^(5/2)))
```

Moreover, the limits of integration over `p` are `{0., 4.64782*10^14}`.  Thus, the exponentials overflow.  Probably, the solution is to restructure the integrand so that it consists instead of terms of the general form

```
-(((29.0983 + 50.3998 I)/
   ((-E^(-116.393 Sqrt[1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + p^2]) + 1) (1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + p^2)^(5/2)))
```

which should avoid the overflows.  I hope that this forensic analysis it helpful and regret that I do not have time to pursue the problem futher.

Comment: Thanks! This already clears up quite a few things. `Cases[%, Hold[Message[...]]]` is a great way to pick out problematic terms out of an unwieldy error-throwing expression (+1 for that alone). Do you know if there is any way to tell Mathematica to do the restructuring that avoids overflow automatically?

Comment: @Casimir  You might process each of the 10 terms in `ΔkerT` separately, and only combine them in the formula for `tfI`.  This will allow you to identify the offending exponentials more readily and recast them to avoid overflows, perhaps by using `Together` to put the each term over a common denominator, multiply its`Numerator` and  `Denomiator by `Exp[-...]`, `Simplify`, and only then recombine the numerator and denominator.  Some experimentation may be required to determine where in the processing to best do this.